# How to split jest e2e tests into multiple files without losing context?

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

So I've written plenty of e2e tests for my backend and this is becoming overwhelming as all of test methods are in one file.

Reason I have all of them in one file is that when my app is created, TypeORM creates in-memory database instance on which I do all of the tests - I need same database to be running across tests as I am doing cross-entities tests.

This part of code is crucial. It initializes app (which also initializes db under the hood):

```
let app: INestApplication;

beforeAll(async () => {
  const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
  }).compile();

  app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
  await app.init();
});
```

Is there a way to somehow transfer `beforeAll()`'s context so that it could be accessed from tests located in other files?

Maybe somehow make `app` global?

Comment: I'm trying something similar these days, but I've so far only managed to extract the inmemory database initialization code using Jest's `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown`. Note that no global context is shared that way, but at least I could start MongoDB and pass its URL in a temporary local file, so it can be used in the individual test suites.

Did you have any more luck with sharing the actual application context?

Comment: Basically, I used https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/mongodb and https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb as my starting points, and then built my own global setup+teardown functions.

Comment: If you're using NodeJS 12+, check out this Jest runner: https://github.com/nicolo-ribaudo/jest-light-runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so kind of a solution is to instead of creating in memory database, you can create a `sqlite` database and force **TypeORM** to create a file (which will be your database) by using:

```
export const e2eConfig: SqliteConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: 'db.db',
  entities: entities,
  synchronize: true,
};
```

(`sqlite` is mostly compatible with `mysql`)

This will make your data persist between tests.